# How does php handle multiple POST requests via AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web page that will have a dynamic number of input fields depending on the user's preference.  I am using AJAX to send the data.  I'm thinking of sending the data one field at a time via individual POST requests to a single php page. That page will look at the variable that has been set and respond appropriately.  If I have a single javascript function that runs a for loop, sending the POST requests as it runs through the input fields, do I get one php session for each POST, or do I get only a single one that begins, runs the script, and ends?

Comment: Why would you make one AJAX request per input file? Put them all in one, unless you have something specific which does different things per input and it all needs done one per one. The PHP session is per "user", not per request.

Comment: The script runs X times, each with the single post request, but it is the same *session* -- a session is not the same thing as a request.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: I don't know how many input fields there will be until the user is ready, since they can add/subtract as needed for their application.  I felt that it was easier to just read each input field in a JS function and POST each field's value, one at a time.  Is that excessive?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: Yes, making an entire HTTP request/response *per field* is excessive.  If it's all going to be sent to the server at the same time, then send it all in one request.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely unnecessary - you can just serialize the whole form (e.g. with jQuery). Can you post the relevant codes?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: I'm still in the design (and learning!) phase, so I don't have much other than the html/JS and a test AJAX http request.  I'll do a bit more thinking and perhaps will post the code in another question when it's ready.  Thanks!

Comment: Having touched on an issue like this very recently, I'd agree that multiple requests is likely to add a LOT of overhead and although it's not trivial necessarily, it's not rocket-science either to have your AJAX request encapsulate the whole form.  Consider having all inputs have the same classname; you could then use getElementsByClassName('foo') ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you clearly understand what "a session" *is,* and how it relates to HTTP and therefore also to AJAX.

Ordinarily, you would bundle-up all the data and send it in one AJAX request, although you can certainly do things any way you like.  Remember that AJAX requests are likely to be processed *in parallel* on the server, and that they might be handled in an unpredictable sequence.  Therefore, it is common practice that "everything that logically 'goes together' is *sent* together, in one AJAX round-trip.

Your "session," meanwhile, would be established once, and then referenced *(implicitly ...)* in all AJAX requests, as well as in any other HTTP or HTTPS activity which occurs.